# PHP booleans var error

Tags: php

I wrote a login script, but it doesn't work:
In this script I can't log in

```
if($_SESSION['logged'] == TRUE){
echo "logged in";
}

if($_POST['pass'] == "blabla"){
$_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
}

if($_GET['logout']){
$_SESSION['logged'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You have several... undefined variables... I don't get it. What do you not understand?

Comment: `===` and `==` are comparison operators and `=` is assignment operator. [http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is loose typed comparison, and `===` is strict typed comparison. Reading the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is a good start.

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 2):

Your first two lines are a comparison:

```
$var1 === TRUE;
$var2 == TRUE;
```

You want them to be a declaration

```
$var1 = TRUE;
$var2 = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not legal syntax for setting a variable

```
var1 === TRUE;
```

And nor is this

```
var2 == TRUE;
```

Use `=` to set a variable to a value.

The `===` and `==` are comparison tests not value assignments.

This is also not going to do a test

```
if($var1 = TRUE){echo "3";}
```

it will set `$var1` to be true, ditto the other 2 times you try this line for `$var2` and `$var3`